# MySQL - allow any user to use a VIEW

Tags: mysql, view

Refiring to the MySQL guide on how to define `GRANT` permissions for a user (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-names.html), I tried the following:

```
DELIMITER $$

..

CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE DEFINER=``@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `my_db`.`my_table` AS (
    ...
)$$


DELIMITER ;
```

But when I try to use that `VIEW` with any user, it says `Access denied for 'my_user'@'my_host'`. So while GRANT might work with empty user as a wildcart for any user, it does not work for `VIEW` definer. What is the proper way of doing it (allowing any user to read data using given `VIEW` in a db)?

I'm using `MySQL 5.5`.

Comment: Do you have an existing user in MySQL with `'my_user'`? are you accessing those in a `localhost`? If yes, have tried editing your code using `'my_user'@'localhost'` instead of `'my_user'@'my_host'`?

Comment: I want to do a wildcart. So ANYUSER@ANYHOST can use the VIEW, not particular user.

Comment: See [Access Control for Stored Programs and Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-programs-security.html): currently every user of the view will attempt to run it under the credentials of a non-existent user `\`\`@\`%\``.  You should set the `DEFINER` to some valid account that has permission to perform the `SELECT`, then with `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` every invoker of the view will run it under that account.  If the defining user has that permission, you can simply use `DEFINER=CURRENT_USER`, which is the default if the `DEFINER` clause is omitted.  `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` is also default.

Comment: Thank you! Could you add this as answer so I can accept it!